# Is if fine to use logs in the Helper Methods?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security

Hi I am having this doubt for a long time whethere to have a logger in methods (usually helper methods) like the one below.

Whether we can print it in the method or print the response where the method is called.

```
    public String getAddNewUserUrl()
    {
        String url             =   null;
        try
        {
            String mode        =   new ModeUtil().getMode();
            String urlToGet    =   ("local".equalsIgnoreCase(mode) ||"staging".equalsIgnoreCase(mode)) ? "staging.url" : "live.url"
            url                =   ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationResources").getString(urlToGet);
            log.info("The url is  : " + url);  // Can we use logs like this
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.log( java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE  , e.getMessage() ,  e );
            log.error("Exception in the method getMode ::"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return url;
}
```

Comment: What is the doubt ? You add logging if needed, otherwise you dont.

Comment: I mean the log should be used within the method or we can print where the response is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.

Use logs wherever you think it is gonna be helpful. Simply use the different levels properly to logically group your logs and avoid mixing very specific ones with general ones.

Comment: and avoid using `e.printStackTrace()`. Use `log.error(e)` instead.

Comment: Yes, that is where i got the doubt.
Do you think that the logs should be removed when it goes to production ? I am new to the production environment.

Comment: No, keep it. You may need it for having information. Just set it correctly so that its size does not threaten your disk if you log a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about how much info you want. I would however log the exception as error, and the user data as debug or even trace.